# How to make a custom grid view

Tags: javascript, html, gridview

[image]
I tried to get the out put as follows,but nothing worked,what am i doing wrong in my code.This is a easy one but im kind of a newbie for this.(ignore the undefined one.)

```
<table class="table table-bordered" id="Tablev">
        <tr input type="hidden" id="trr"><th></tr>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr input type="hidden" id="date" style="display:none;" class="th-hidden-date"></tr>     
        <tr></tr>
    </table>
```

```
for (var i = 0; i <= days; i++) {
'</td>').appendTo($('#trr'));
var input = `<input type="hidden" id="date" value=${result1[i]} class="th-hidden-date" />`
$('<td>' + result1[i] + input + '</td>').appendTo($('#trr'));
}
$.each(Item1, function (index, item) {
var hiddenValues = [];
$('#Tablev').find('input:hidden').each(function () {                         
$('<tr>' +
'<td>' + item.itemname + '</td>' + '<td>' + item[$(this).val()] + '</td>').appendTo($('#Tablev'));

});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to fix some parts of your code:

```
<table class="table table-bordered" id="Tablev">
    <tr input type="hidden" id="trr"><th></tr> // This <th> need closure and shouldn't be there.
    <tr></tr>
    <tr input type="hidden" id="date" style="display:none;" class="th-hidden-date"></tr>     
    <tr></tr>
</table>
```

Let me fix this for you, at least partially...

```
<table class="table table-bordered" id="Tablev">
 <thead>
  <th></th>
  <th></th> // This th will be filled with the dates..
  <th></th> // This th will be filled with the dates..
  <th></th> // This th will be filled with the dates..
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td> <input type="hidden" id="trr"> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr></tr>
  <tr>
   <td> <input type="hidden" id="date" style="display:none;" class="th-hidden-date"> </td>
  </tr>     
  <tr></tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Now, i can't understand why you hide these `<tr>`, now with `JQuery` you can do something like:

```
var trow = '</tr><td>'+ result[i] + '<input type="hidden" id="date" value="'+result[i]+'" class="th-hidden-date" /></td></tr>';
$('#trr').append(trow);
```

Note that u have some mistakes in the code, see the diff and practice about using " " or ' ' when insert vars inside HTML.
Put some id's in the `<th>` tags to easy fill them.

I'm not expert and i hope this can help to fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

i not find out what are u want , but i guess u should have a 2D array and every row id one of cell of array

```
[['Allocated',0,0,undefinded],['out of order',0,0,undefined],...]
```

then in loop (for) in each step of loop u should fill one row complete

Comment: As you can see in the image i got the following output but i want to pass the output as blue arrows @AlirezaHejazi